# Deep Wildcard Sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

How do I define deep wildcards in sailsjs?

For example, I can create a wildcard in `mysite.com/slug/wildcard` by adding `/slug/:wildcard/` to my route.

However, this doesn't work: `mysite.com/slug/wildcard/extended/`. I want to be able to capture all the routes that start with `slug`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible with the current revision of sails, as route parameters are defined using `:param` .. each instance of `:something` indicates a new param for the route handler. These are not called wildcards but parameters.

I know express supports `*` for a wildcard, have you tried something like this...

```
'/slug/*': {
  controller: 'Index',
  action: 'index'
},
```